# Right Arrow Is missed in daterangepicker - Angular

Tags: angular, daterangepicker, angular-daterangepicker

I have used `daterangepicker` in my angular component with the following options:

```
optionsSingle = {
    startDate: moment(),
    endDate: moment(),
    minDate: moment(),
    locale: {
      format: "DD/MM/YYYY"
    },
    alwaysShowCalendars: true,
    autoApply: true,
    singleDatePicker: true,
    opens: "left"
  };
```

I used a single date picker.

[image: Right navigation icon is not visible to me]

[image: Can anybody help me on this?]

Comment: It is not missed it is a feature where the user it disabled to select the future date or year.

Comment: If the arrow was shown, what would it do if clicked? `endDate` is defined as today (`moment()`).

Comment: Ok. If I remove enddate and mindate, still the icon is not showing